# Any altmetrics statistics for physics papers?

Tags: physics, bibliometrics, impact-factor

I am interested in how many papers (especially in physics literature) have this certain altmetric score (see more on www.altmetric.com). I have looked in several journals e.g. Physical Review and have seen that many papers in physics have altmetrics score of 1 or 0. If it is 1 it relies upon a few tweeters only.

Is it really so that altmetrics score for physics Research papers is low? If yes, why it is mostly so low?
How many physics papers (estimated) have an altmetrics score of

- Zero
- 1 to 9
- 10 to 30
- more than 30?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this spam advertising for the mentioned website? Is there a source that defines "altmetric" as you are using it?

Comment: Definitely not spam - altmetrics is a website, but also a movement. See the [Declaration on Research Assessment](http://www.ascb.org/dora/) for example. Altmetrics just does analysis on the different ways people "cite" research, including links on websites,  blogs, social media etc.

Comment: So, I don't have an answer, but part of the phenomenon may be how Altmetrics counts. Most physics papers appear  first in ArXiv and the ArXiv identifiers are used when people talk about them on the web. If Altmetrics doesn't count those, that may explain the low scores. However, it's certainly true that there is a _lot_ of chatter on the web in the physics world, about current research, so the low altmetric scores are certainly biased measurements.